# how to specify ldap server address when binding to the ldap server?

Tags: python, networking, firewall, python-ldap

I am trying ldap authentication. My ldap server is located at x.x.x.x . I am using python-ldap. Connection on server locally doing:

```
ldap.initialize('ldap://localhost:389')
```

works fine,
but when i try to connect to the server from another machine, doing:

```
ldap.initialize('ldap://x.x.x.x:389')
```

it **doesnt work**.
What is it that I should do?

Comment: Start by making sure there's no firewall blocking traffic on port 389 and that the LDAP server is listening on 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1

Comment: thanks, it worked. the firewall was blocking the traffic on port 389.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by way of lifting firewall-based restrictions.